# Javascript special character not printing correctly

Tags: javascript, special-characters

My problem is Getting

`�`

instead '™' Javascript.

I have a HTML page in which I have form using which I am sending a file to servlet.

Servlet processes the file and returns 'response' which is in JSON format.

This JSON includes '™' characters in its value. As I am printing json in servlet '™' is printing correctly.

But when I am returning this JSON to HTML page and when I try to print it on console, It is printing  like `�`.

How can I get actual value..?

**Here is the code snippet.**

```
success : function(response) 
                    {
                        console.log(response);    //printing `�`
                        resp = JSON.parse(response);
                        console.log(resp);       // printing `�`
                    }
```

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: what do you got in your html head?

Comment: Note that JSON is UTF8 and Java Strings are UTF16 so you need to serve your JSON as UTF8 bytes, so you would need to do something like  byte[] outbuff = mystring.getBytes("UTF-8");

Comment: @GeorgiosMoralis JSON is not *necessarily* UTF-8. And what has Java got to do with anything?! (Also, any JSON parser worth anything would take care of such things for you.)

Comment: He is saying that he is serving it from a Servlet so I guessed it could be a Java Servlet problem since doing just mystring.getBytes() in Java would return the bytes of an UTF16 string and that would mess up any non English letters.

Comment: @FanyoSILIADIN I have not specified anything....tried `<meta charset="UTF-16">` also with UTF-8.. but no luck.

Comment: @GeorgiosMoralis after getting it into byte[] , how would I put it into JSON..?

Comment: Atually in servlet I am reading data from excel file and then putting it into JSON....and sending that JSON in response..... which contains '™'

Comment: @PankajShinde You would need to set the Content-Type header to the JSON MIME (application/json) and you would have to write the bytes directly to the output with response.getOutputStream().write(outbuff);

Comment: @GeorgiosMoralis Yes, I have set not set the ContentType of response to 'application/json'...
And I am using  `response.getOutputStream().write(responseJsonObject.toJSONString().getBytes());`

Comment: Thank you guys.. solved it.!!!
following is the change : 

`response.getOutputStream().write(responseJsonObject.toJSONString().getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using UTF-8 character encoding in the response.
Following line solved it :

`response.getOutputStream().write(responseJsonObject.toJSONString().getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Answer (score 0):

Try one of this one : `&#8482;` or  `&trade;`